# Why in python range (0,x**2+1) very slow?

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
def(x):
    for i in range (0,x**2+1):
        ...
```

But I found it is very slow!!
Who can tell me the reason,thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of 'very slow'? This is also definitely not valid code. I imagine the actual reason for slowness is elsewhere in your actual code, not the `x**2`.

Comment: No. Rather it's very quick at raising a `SyntaxError`. What is your complete code?

Comment: What's the value of  `x`?

Answer (score 8):

In Python 2.x: `range` creates a list of all the numbers up to the stop parameter (which looks to be huge in your case).

You can try using `xrange` instead which creates an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: The other answer would be that `x**2` is slower than `x*x` because the latter is a simple multiplication while the former is a more complex operation with a variable exponent.

Comment: @poke - well, that is not a time difference the OP could notice.

Comment: @poke: I find that `x**2` is actually slightly faster than `x*x`, maybe (I'm guessing here) because `LOAD_CONST` is faster than `LOAD_GLOBAL`.  (Update: and `x**2.0` is slower, so there must be specialization on the type, doing the usual cleverness for integer arguments.)  At this level you're usually measuring Python implementation overhead.

Comment: @DSM `x*x` is way faster though. (And in my test, `x**2.0` is actually faster than `x**2` o.O)

Comment: @poke: I don't agree that `x*x` is way faster, at least for integer arguments (things are different with floats).   I get 80 ns for `x**2` and 90 for `x*x`.